# How to shorten the width of a single pulse

Tags: pulse

I want to shorten the width of a single pulse to 50ms or 100ms width. For example, a circuit generates a positive pulse of duration 1 sec and I need to reduce its width to 50ms, synchronized to the rising edge of the input pulse. How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Is this for 5V logic?

Answer (score 3):

What you want is called a *monostable multivibrator*, or *one-shot* for short.  You set it up to trigger on the leading edge of your signal.  It will the produce a pulse of fixed duration.

You set the duration with timing components, like a resistor and capacitor.  There are 74xxx series chips that are intended for exactly this purpose.  Look thru a selector guide.

Comment: I would recommend to use a non retriggerable monoflop for this task.

Comment: Thank you, can you suggest a schematic. I can calculate the rc timing. All I want is the the circuit to work when the output pulse width be shorter than the input.

Comment: I 've managed to work with 74ls122. thanks